# Equivalent of View in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I was wondering how do you change views. If I'm wanting to display different things inside the `index.html` (change the view), how am I supposed to do this?

Has the approach of using views been replaced with using components and templates?

I have this so far in my app.module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [


{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'construction',
    component: ConstructionComponent
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: PageNotFoundComponent 
  }
];
```

Comment: Let me know if anything else is needed but I'm sure I've provided everything needed in terms of the question in hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views were just an `HTML` file with a `Controller` linked to it. It's not really different in `Angular 2`.

You do not define the `HTML View` anymore in your configuration file, you define a `Component` (which is the equivalent of a `Controller`), and the `View` is now defined directly in the `Component`.

So, to clarify, you have to define a path and a `Component`, and it will render the `View` you want. Just like before. Don't hesitate to check the official documentation about [routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)